# String replacement in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string that has *formal* args within brackets and the actual args in an array. In the expression below, I need to replace the formal with actual args. Looking for options in Ruby to do this cleanly..

```
string = "[m,n] { m + n * 8  + aa }"
array = [12, false]
output = "{ 12 + false * 8 + aa }"
```

Comment: raw ruby, nothing clean. not sure if treetop etc is the right solution, could be more than what i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def convert( expression, *input_values )
  params = /^\[([^\]]+)\]\s*/
  keys   = expression[params,1].split(',')
  map    = Hash[ keys.zip(input_values) ]
  key_re = /\b(?:#{keys.join('|')})\b/

  expression.sub(params,'').gsub(key_re){ |key| map[key] }
end

p convert( "[m,n] { m + n * 8  + aa }", 12, false )
#=> "{ 12 + false * 8  + aa }"
```

How this works:

1. Take the expression and find the names in it; call it `keys`
2. Create a hash that maps the key names to the values passed in, e.g. `{"m"=>12, "n"=>false}`.
3. Create a single regex that looks for all keys as their own word, e.g. `/\b(?:m|n)\b/`

   - *This is so that a string value in one replacement is not accidentally replaced later on.*
4. Strip the formal parameters from the input expression, and then,
5. Find the keys regex and for each found value replace it with the value from the hash.

Comment: This is the way to go.. I like it *+1*..

Answer (score 0):

If your end goal is to evaluate the string using the arguments supplied, you could do this:

```
aa = 7
args = [12, 6]
str = "[m,n] { m + n * 8 + aa }"

proc_str = "-> " + str.sub("[","(").sub("]",")") # "-> (m,n) { m + n * 8 + aa }"
eval(proc_str).call(*args) # => 67
```

Comment: using eval is a huge risk should be avoided if possible

Comment: That's absurd.  It's only risky when one blindly applies `eval` to user input. I know your view is widely held, but I can't imagine why.

Comment: you can't guess what the use case of the code is, so suggesting eval here might be more destructive, however I commend your solution

Comment: @CarySwoveland There is nothing wrong with using `eval` per se, but the OP seems to want a string, not the whole evaluation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Are you using HHKB?

Comment: @sawa.  Just got the HHKB.  Very nice.  Also switching to VIM.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's good combination.

Comment: I just don't want people to equate `eval` with fear. [Peter Cooper](http://books.google.ca/books?id=A78bYfzYKZ4C&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=ruby+eval+essential&source=bl&ots=vFknghi4AG&sig=Ox2wsBUxfaSiwHWcaOKbRqLRYN0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4BeRUtyWKsHpqgHYz4HQBA&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=eval%28&f=false)'s take on `eval` and its close cousins (p. 278): "String interpolation makes the eval methods powerful tools for generating different features on the fly.  This ability is a power unseen in the majority of programming languages, is one that's used to great effect in systems such as Ruby on Rails."

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are completely right. I have seen this kind of claims against `eval`, and mostly the claim is made my people who cannot think by themselves, and are just repeating what others say.

Comment: @sawa, Now that I'm getting used to VIM with my HHKB, smoke is coming from the keyboard.  If you can offer any suggestions, please let me know by email (see my profile).